# How to prove that $q+1$ divides $q^k - 1$ for $k \in 2 \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to prove that if $k \in 2 \mathbb N $ every $q+1$ divides $q^k-1$ and I really have trouble understanding how to do this.

Comment: $q+1$ dividing $q^{2k}-1$ is the same as $q=-1$ being a zero of $q^{2k}-1$...

Comment: Factor $x^2 -1$ and $x^4 -1$ and $x^6-1$ and look for a pattern you can prove.

Comment: By the linked dupe: $\large \ q+1\mid q^2-1\mid q^{2n}-1\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$q^{2k}-1=(q^2-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}q^{2j}$, while  $q^2-1=(q-1)(q+1)$.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you know modular arithmetic, note $q\equiv-1\pmod {q+1}$.

Raise both sides to the $k^{th}$ power, and subtract $1$ from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will gain insight into this problem by performing [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).

For $k = 2$, you have (showing intermediate steps)
\begin{align*}
& \begin{array}{c|ccc}
   &  1  & 0 &  -1  \\
-1 &     &   &      \\ \hline
   &  1  &   &       
\end{array}  \\
& \begin{array}{c|ccc}
   &  1  &  0 &  -1  \\
-1 &     & -1 &      \\ \hline
   &  1  & -1 &       
\end{array}  \\
& \begin{array}{c|ccc}
   &  1  &  0 &  -1  \\
-1 &     & -1 &   1  \\ \hline
   &  1  & -1 &   0   
\end{array}  \\
\end{align*}
This shows you have remainder zero.  Repeating for one or two more $k$ should make the pattern of coefficients in the cofactor clear.

Answer (score 1):

$((q+1)-1)^{2m}-1=$

$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2m}}\binom{2m}{k}(q+1)^{2m-k}(-1)^k-1=$

$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1}}\binom{2m}{k}(q+1)^{2m-k}(-1)^k.$

All terms contain a factor $(q+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{aligned}
q^{2n}-1&=(q^2-1)(1+ q^2 + \dots + q^{2n-2})\\
&=(q-1)(q+1)(1+ q^2 + \dots + q^{2n-2})
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Correct, of course. I would rather you'd waited or hinted to give the OP more time to struggle first.

Comment: @EthanBolker That is a fair remark. I was challenging myself to remember geometric progression identities quickly.